# How to pass data from php-fpm into nginx access log?

Tags: nginx, php

I'm trying to find bottlenecks in a PHP application by logging request URL and `$request_time` in nginx. Unfortunately, `$request_time` includes network lag, which I cannot optimize. I want the log to include another field with pure page generation time, so I can compare it to the `$request_time`.

I assume for slow connections nginx fetches the php-fpm output quickly and then waits for the client do download it. I can measure generation time in PHP, but how do I put it into the nginx access log?

Comment: Change php-fpm log format to one you desire and point it to nginx log file, that's it.

Comment: As soon as PHP respond, the content will be returned to the client. If you're running Nginx in the same machine as PHP, there's no network lag. Even if you're using TCP instead of unix socket, it's only slightly different. Is it a busy server? How many request/sec doest it receive on avg?

Answer (score 2):

Put the data you want nginx to log into a header via PHP.

```
header('RequestTime', 1234);
```

Ask nginx to log the value of the header to file in your nginx config.

```
log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
              '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
              '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" $upstream_http_requesttime';
```

Note that this value will also be sent to the client via the Headers, therefore nothing of sensitive nature should be included in the extra headers.

Comment: I tried this solution, but unfortunately, a `-` appeared in the logs instead of the header value. Turns out, this solution was pretty close: instead of using `$http_requesttime`, use `$upstream_http_requesttime`. I managed to prevent the header being sent to the client with `fastcgi_hide_header RequestTime` (assuming you're using fastcgi to interface with php-fpm).